# How to list the permissions on User-Defined Table Types?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, sql-server-2012, permissions, user-defined-type

I am using some user-defined table types. They are very useful.

you can see information about them by running this simple script:

```
SELECT o.* from sys.table_types o
```

I have a procedure that shows me all the permissions on the user objects. I can specify the name of the object too.
the code is this:

```
DECLARE @OBJ SYSNAME
SELECT @OBJ ='%'  -- shows all objects 
;WITH
RADHARANI AS (

                SELECT
                    dp.NAME AS principal_name
                        ,dp.type_desc AS principal_type_desc
                        ,o.NAME AS object_name
                        ,o.type_desc
                        ,p.permission_name
                        ,p.state_desc AS permission_state_desc
                    FROM sys.all_objects  o
                        INNER JOIN sys.database_permissions  p ON o.OBJECT_ID=p.major_id
                        LEFT OUTER JOIN sys.database_principals  dp ON p.grantee_principal_id = dp.principal_id
                   WHERE O.OBJECT_ID > 0
                     AND O.TYPE <> 'S'    -- no system
                     AND O.parent_object_id = 0 -- no constraints
                     AND o.NAME like @OBJ

)


SELECT * FROM RADHARANI
SELECT @@ROWCOUNT
```

On my above code, I don't list the permissions on my User-Defined Table Types.

How can I achieve that?

[image]

These are the permissions I grant to my type so that the users can use it:

```
USE [Bocss2]
GO

--=====================================================
-- create the DespatchStatus table type 
-- if it does not exist already
--=====================================================
IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * from sys.table_types) BEGIN

            CREATE TYPE [dbo].[DespatchStatus] AS TABLE(
                lngDespatchStatusID int not null
            ,PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED(lngDespatchStatusID)

            )
END
GO
use [Bocss2]
GO
GRANT REFERENCES ON TYPE::[dbo].[DespatchStatus] TO [WebDevelopment]
GO
GRANT VIEW DEFINITION ON TYPE::[dbo].[DespatchStatus] TO [WebDevelopment]
GO
GRANT EXECUTE ON TYPE::[dbo].[DespatchStatus] TO [WebDevelopment] AS [dbo]
GO
```

And this is how it is used inside stored procedures:

```
--=====================================================
-- declare and populate the DespatchStatus
--=====================================================
DECLARE @DIS DespatchStatus;
INSERT INTO @DIS(lngDespatchStatusID) VALUES (7)
INSERT INTO @DIS(lngDespatchStatusID) VALUES (11)
INSERT INTO @DIS(lngDespatchStatusID) VALUES (17)
INSERT INTO @DIS(lngDespatchStatusID) VALUES (19)
```

At the end, inspired by Aaron's answer my permission script became as follows:
(using UNION ALL)

```
 DECLARE @OBJ SYSNAME
        SELECT @OBJ ='%'  -- shows all objects 
        ;WITH
        RADHARANI AS (

                        SELECT
                            dp.NAME AS principal_name
                                ,dp.type_desc AS principal_type_desc
                                ,o.NAME AS object_name
                                ,o.type_desc
                                ,p.permission_name
                                ,p.state_desc AS permission_state_desc
                            FROM sys.all_objects  o
                                INNER JOIN sys.database_permissions  p ON o.OBJECT_ID=p.major_id
                                LEFT OUTER JOIN sys.database_principals  dp ON p.grantee_principal_id = dp.principal_id
                           WHERE O.OBJECT_ID > 0
                             AND O.TYPE <> 'S'    -- no system
                             AND O.parent_object_id = 0 -- no constraints
                             AND o.NAME like @OBJ

                       UNION ALL

                        SELECT
                            dp.NAME AS principal_name
                                ,dp.type_desc AS principal_type_desc
                                ,o.NAME AS object_name
                                ,[type_desc] = 'User-Defined Table Type' 
                                ,p.permission_name
                                ,p.state_desc AS permission_state_desc
                            FROM sys.table_types  o
                                INNER JOIN sys.database_permissions  p ON o.user_type_id=p.major_id
                                LEFT OUTER JOIN sys.database_principals  dp ON p.grantee_principal_id = dp.principal_id
                           WHERE o.NAME like @OBJ

        )


        SELECT * FROM RADHARANI
        SELECT @@ROWCOUNT
```

and as you can see on the picture below, my table type is displayed with its permissions, after all the objects.

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This will list explicitly granted permissions on table types, but not those granted implicitly through role or group membership, or permissions granted against the containing schema.

```
SELECT 
  [schema] = s.name, 
  [type] = t.name, 
  [user] = u.name, 
  p.permission_name, 
  p.state_desc
FROM sys.database_permissions AS p
INNER JOIN sys.database_principals AS u
  ON p.grantee_principal_id = u.principal_id
INNER JOIN sys.types AS t
  ON p.major_id = t.user_type_id--.[object_id]
INNER JOIN sys.schemas AS s
  ON t.[schema_id] = s.[schema_id]
WHERE p.class = 6; -- TYPE
```

I am curious what type of explicit permissions you are using in your system for table types? From [the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174346.aspx) there isn't a whole lot you need to implement for standard runtime query support (you can't grant `SELECT` directly, for example). It seems this is mostly there for metadata / control.

Comment: I have updated the question to show the permissions I grant to the table type. Without the EXECUTE, for example, they cannot run a stored procedure that declares a DespatchStatus.